# Alternative to user:pass@domain.com

Tags: php, authentication

Is there an alternative to http://user:pass@domain.com?

I have a php script with a link

```
<a href='user:pass@domain.com'>LINK</a>
```

When I click on it it takes me to the website and saves me having to authenticate every time. It normally has a pop up box. The flaw is that if you hover over the link it shows the user and pass. Is there an alternative that won't do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a password storage application/wallet system to store usernames and passwords. It saves you the hassle of making these kinds of things, and works equally well when the site in question uses something other than basic HTTP authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to this:

- HTML code:

  ```
  <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" title="">Link 1</a>

  <a href="#" title="" data-location="http://www.google.com/">Link 2</a>
  ```
- JavaScript (using jQuery):

  ```
  jQuery().delegate('a[data-location]', 'click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      window.location = jQuery(this).attr('data-location');
  });
  ```

It will just catch clicks on specific links (links, that contain `data-location` attributes) and redirect to the location from the `data-location` attributes. In the example it should catch only *Link 2* and redirect you to www.google.com.

Comment: @Michael: It is not meant to. It is meant to prevent going to the standard (`href`) URL, if different URL is provided within `data-location`. I did not test it, but the idea is simple and I see no reason for it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide part of link if you have basic HTTP authentication

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.php.net/manual/features.http-auth.php